# To display the object properties even after page reload in get() set() method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 2 components called `list` and `home`, I will display some objects of the array called `contacts` in `list` component as shown below.

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
 <mat-card (click)="onClick(contact)" >
    <h4>{{contact.contactName}}</h4>
    <p>{{contact.email}}</p>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

When i click on the particular object(i,e contact). I will set the clicked `object` using `set()` method.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService} from '../data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts = [];
  constructor(private myService: ContactService,
  private router : Router,
  private dataService: DataService,
  ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getContacts()
      .subscribe((res :[]) => this.contacts = res);
  }
  onClick(contact) {
    this.dataService.setSelectedContact(contact);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

}
```

Then i will be routed a `home` component and i will access the clicked object using `get()` method like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService} from '../data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  contact: any;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contact = this.dataService.getSelectedContact();
    console.log(this.contact);
  }

}
```

`service` file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  selectedContact;
  constructor() { }

  public setSelectedContact(data) {
    this.selectedContact = data;
  }

  public getSelectedContact() : any {
    return this.selectedContact;
  }

}
```

When i route for the first time i am able to display the the clicked `object` but if i refresh the page i can't display the `object`, The object will become `undefined`, How can i display object even after refreshing the page(home)?

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-xekvvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)**

Comment: Use `ngOnchange`.

Comment: By refreshing, do you mean refresh the whole website from the browser or just navigating to the different components?

Comment: Refreshing the whole website.

Comment: Then you need to use for example `localStorage`. If you refresh the app, all data is lost otherwise.

Comment: Think about accepting one of the answers and if these did not satisfy you please stay in the loop and indicate what you are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are stored in the memory and are lost after refreshing the website.
Use cookies to store information on the client's machine.

Install:

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service --save
```

Import it to your module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
  providers: [ CookieService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And use it in your component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
cookieValue = 'UNKNOWN';

constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.cookieService.set( 'Test', 'Hello World' );
  this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('Test');
}
```

Here is the complete guide for [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the browser cache or a cookie to remember the most recently selected (clicked) object or even store this data server-side.

Also, consider using "real" getters and setters like this:

```
public set SelectedContact(value: any) {
    this.selectedContact = value;
  }

  public get SelectedContact() : any {
    return this.selectedContact;
  }
```